# How to only call print once?

Tags: python

```
number = input('Please enter a number: ')

number = int(number)

if number > 1:
    print(number)

else:
    print(-number)
```

test results shows that output are true but the only reason is can only call print once, I have no idea how to fix the print, can someone help pls thanks!

Comment: You will only call print once right now right? Since either number is larger than 1 or not larger than 1? Can you explain what is wrong a little clearer?

Comment: Currently it prompts for a number, inputs a string, converts it to an integer, then prints either `number` or `-number` depending on whether it's greater than one or not.  It's almost like `abs(number)`, except for `1` it will print `-1`.  That describes what it does now.  So, what do you *want* it to do that it isn't doing now?  That information is not at all clear from the question.

Comment: The Python test result errors then said you should only call print once, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional expression:

```py
print(number if number > 1 else -number)
```

Comment: This will give the correct result but it is not very readable, and for harder problems it gets even harder to code like this.

Comment: you code is correct but I have to use the if statement so can you use if statement then only print once based on my code? thanks!

Comment: @GustavD I disagree, in my opinion this makes the code easier to understand because it is directly clear what the effect of the condition is (i.e. negating the number or not). With the `if` statement version, this is not immediately clear as both branches (`if` and `else`) contain more code than the actual condition wants to modify. Consider for example `foo(bar(baz(number)))`; do you really want to repeat those three function calls inside every conditional branch? `foo(bar(baz(number if ... else ...)))` however makes it clear that the condition only modifies `number`, not the function calls.

Comment: @Win What do you mean by "you have to use ..."? If the code works, it works.

Comment: @a_guest Putting if statements inside print statements only works for small if statements. Since our asker is new, I think it's better to not using esoteric python syntax and doing it in a simple way.

Comment: @GustavD As I mentioned above, the idea behind a conditional expression *is* to be able to limit the conditional *only* to the small part that is relevant. Obviously that's not the right tool in all cases, but for the OP's use case it's well suited.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you want to only have one "print" statement, like, only writing "print" once?

You can use the if/else to change the value of number and then after that print whatever the result is.

```
if number < 2:
    number = -number
print(number)
```

Will give you the same answer with one print statement as after number is changed to "-number" you will exit the "if" block.

Comment: This has *very different* semantics than the OP's code; the two are not compatible. Your code permanently modifies `number` while OP's code only does that as an argument to `print`.

Comment: @a_guest I'm making a small assumption on what he is trying to do. I seriously doubt it matters what value number has after the print.